# How do I use htaccess to redirect to a new domain except for the site index?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm working to migrate an entire site to a new server and need to setup htaccess so that it properly redirects old content while handling new content, too.

The old domain is a simple landing page that consists of an index.html page and three directories: /images, /styles, /fonts.

Whenever someone navigates to the old domain, I'd like the landing page to load. That is, if the user navigates to:

- http://OldDomain.com
- http://OldDomain.com/
- http://OldDomain.com/index.html

Then they remain on said URL.

In *any other case,* I'd like to perform a 301 redirect. For example:

- http://OldDomain.com/about redirects to http://NewDomain.com/about
- http://OldDomain.com/this-is-the-title redirects to http://NewDomain.com/this-is-the-title

Unfortunately, I can't quite seem to nail the proper regular expression to handle the initial cases for the landing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# for http    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule . http://NewDomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# for https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule . https://NewDomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```